# Custom vscode extension - how to react on text changes in editor (not file - before save)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing my custom vscode extension and for now I have several commands triggered by right click context menu.

Now I would like to add possibility for user, who doesn't like clicks just to write code and display context menu during writing.

Or just react base on typed text (like snippets, but instead of autocomplete, just run my custom command)

So flow is following:
User starts to type 'fooC'
option a) Some listener subscribe and run command FooCommand.
option b) List of available commands is displayed (like context menu during writing)

Is it possible with vscode API ? Do you have any ideas or workarounds ?

Comment: You could register a command in _package.json_ and contribute it to _Command Palette_ just run this command by pressing Ctrl+Shift+P or F1 [see here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.commands), if that is what you want to do.

Comment: Implement a CompletionItem provider

Comment: Or listen to this: `vscode.window.onDidChangeTextEditorSelection(event)`.

Comment: @riov8 this is exactly what I needed. Thank you a lot ! CompletionItem with command and insertText is the feature I needed.